# Py: The command pyinstaller could not be found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert a script to an executable with pyinstaller, but pyinstaller won't work.

I've tried installing it for 3.8 and 3.7, but neither works. How do I know what versions pyinstaller is available for, or what am I doing wrong? It just tells me that there is no command called pyinstaller.

Commands I tried:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py

pyinstaller.exe --onefile main.py

py -3 pyinstaller --onefile main.py

py -3 pyinstaller.exe --onefile main.py

py -3.7 pyinstaller --onefile main.py

py -3.7 pyinstaller.exe --onefile main.py

py -3.8 pyinstaller --onefile main.py

py -3.8 pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pyinstaller`? The -m flag runs a *m*odule. I don't really know anything about pyinstaller, but this is generally what should be done most of the time.

Comment: Yes, does not work either

Comment: did you use the command `pip install PyInstaller` to install pyinstaller first?

Comment: like I said, I installed it for 3.7 and 3.8

Answer (score 1):

If on Unix-like OS (Linux, *BSD, probably MacOS): https://superuser.com/questions/1310800/pyinstaller-command-not-found

If pip says the module is installed, the binary is somewhere on your system. On most *nix systems, you can use the `find` command. On windows, [the `where` command should do something similar](https://superuser.com/questions/1310800/pyinstaller-command-not-found). Once you find it, you can create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) or copy it to a directory where you or the OS can find and run it.

If pip is having trouble installing it, that's a completely different issue. If the above solution doesn't work, paste the output of `pip install pyinstaller` into a new question about pip failing to install pyinstaller rather than the OS being unable to find pyinstaller.

Comment: I am still not sure if it is a compatibility issue or if the path is not set right(I'm guessing it's the second one) but i think you brought me into the right direction, thanks

Comment: yes, to add on this, if you run from windows, "where" -- you should see the pyinstaller.exe if it is installed.